# Problems using PieChart of achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm facing problems using PieChart from the achartengine library. According to the demo, the PieChart extends `AbstractChart.java`, not `AbstractChart.class` in the library. Hence, the functions `buildCategoryRenderer(int[] args)` and `buildCategoryDataset(String arg0, double[] arg1)` don't exist in the library.

How does one initiate a PieChart and show it as an separate intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the instructions [here](http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html) in order to download and setup the AChartEngine demo into your IDE. Then, take a look at BudgetPieChart. It extends the AbstractChart class that is located into the same demo package.

However, from version 0.6.0, the AbstractChart will be renamed to AbstractDemoChart to avoid naming issues.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is too late, just putting for people stumble up on the same question:

http://xebee.xebia.in/2010/08/31/exploring-android-charting-and-graphs-solutions/

In this link the author shows how to use achartengine without using the abstract classes and interfaces like AbstractChart and Ichart